# Vim: Find text in a specific column

Tags: vim, find

When searching for text in Vim (specifically gVim, but it shouldn't matter), how do you specify what column to search? I'm looking for values in one column only.

Comment: text files generally don't have columns. Or are you talking about character columns?

Comment: Yes, text at a certain position in the line, for example, the 5th character of the line.

Comment: Related: [How do I move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-move-vertically-until-reaching-a-non-whitespace-character) at Vi SE

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Even, if I tend to use the same solution as roe, you can also use \%c -> `:h /\%c`

EDIT:
For those who don't find the documentation very explicit.

Let say my buffer contains

```
dog
1dog
12dog
123dog
1324dog
12345dog
132465dog
```

Then, `:echo search('\%5cdog')` would give me: 5 (the line number 5).

You could also set `'hlsearch'` to on -> `:set hlsearch` and observe the which text matches on `/\%5cdog`, `/\%<5cdog` and `\%>5cdog`

Comment: I think this is the best answer of the lot. %c was specifically made for specifying columns in regexps.

Comment: This is really opaque.  I've been using vim for a while and don't understand what you are saying.  Can you edit it a bit and make it idiot proof?  E.g. if you are searching for 'dog' in column 5 it would look like what?  Thanks!

Comment: I gave the entry point to the documentation as myself, I never remember how it is used. I just only remember this exists. Now, let's see the doc.... If I want to match dog at 5th column, I would search for `\%5cdog` -- the search itself would be done with `/`, or `:substitute`, or `:global`, or `search()`, ...

Comment: @LucHermitte: Thank you. This tip was extremely helpful to navigate a big dump file. Without this I was hoping to modify the dump file format to make it easier to navigate. Thanks to you and vim, I don't have to anymore!

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about character columns, then you might have luck with `/^.\{33\}mytext/` which will search your file for 'mytext' beginning at column 34. Note that the number in the search is one less than the column you want (it's matching 33 characters of anything at the beginning of the line, followed by your text).

Answer (score 2):

You could use some sort of visual selection and then `:/(searchterm)` to find what you're looking for. For instance CTRL+V allows you to do column selections, then with everything selected do `:/(term) <enter>`.